# Angular - using typeahead in input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I want to use Typeahead in my Bootstrap's input. I get information and storage in $scope.regions . Here is my code :

**myfile.js:**

```
            $scope.selectedRegion = "";
            $scope.regions =  res.data.result;
```

And Here is screenshot of my element:

[image]

I want to use regionName as typeahead in input. Here is my HTML code for input:

```
<input placeholder="select region" class="form-control form-xs typeahead" ng-model="selectedRegion" typeahead="region for region in regions($viewValue)">
```

And I want to check regionName in list like this :

```
            <li ng-repeat="region in regions">
              <a href = "#"> {{ region.regionName }} </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

Well , I can see result of list. but Typeahead is not working , I mean that box of typeahead under input does not appear . Any suggestion?

Comment: User input is getting cleared every time in myfile.js $http.get request. Remove the  $scope.selectedRegion = ""; statement.

Comment: I remove it but still it's not working

Comment: Explain more clearly about what is not working ?

Comment: @tejesh95 I mean that box of typeahead under input does not appear.

Comment: create a function (ex `autocompleteRegions()` ) in your controller who filter the data and return them as an simple array. then call this function in the input typehead : `typeahead="item for item in autocompleteRegions($viewValue)"`

Comment: @AlainIb Put it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the typeahead I mentioned below. Because you need to get the value of regionName alone and you cannot parse the object in the typeahead.

```
<input placeholder="select region" class="form-control form-xs typeahead" ng-model="selectedRegion" typeahead="region.regionName for region in regions($viewValue)">
```

or else add the onselect function to test the value coming in the typeahead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter

```
 <input placeholder="select region" class="form-control form-xs typeahead" ng-model="selectedRegion" typeahead="region for region in regions | filter:$viewValue">
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a function in your controller (ex `autocompleteRegions()` ) who filter the data and return them as an simple array :

```
    // test if string start with prefix 
    function stringStartsWith (string, prefix) {
        var minl = ( prefix.length < string.length ) ? prefix.length : string.length ;
        return string.slice(0, minl) == prefix.slice(0, minl);
    }
    $scope.autocompleteRegions = function(value){
         var returnMe  = [];
         // find with regionName begin with "value"
         for(var i in $scope.regions){
             if(stringStartsWith($scope.regions[i]["regionName"],value){
                 returnMe.push(  $scope.regions[i]["regionName"] ) ;
             } 
         }
         return returnMe ;
    }
```

Then call this function in the input typehead

```
     <input typeahead="item for item in autocompleteRegions($viewValue)">
```